# how to partition the matrix into blocks of different dimensions

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, partitions

i have a matrix

```
A =
{{3., -1., 0, -1., 0, -1., 0},
 {-1., 2., -1., 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, -1.,1., 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {-1., 0, 0, 2., -1., 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, -1., 1., 0, 0},
 {-1., 0, 0, 0, 0, 2., -1.},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1., 1.}}
```

I want to partition in the form

```
{{A11,A12,A13,A14},
 {A21,A22,A23,A24},
 {A31,A32,A33,A34},
 {A41,A42,A43,A44}}
```

where

```
A11={3};
A12=A13=A14={-1,0};
A21=A31=A41={{-1},{0}};
A22=A33=A44={{2,-1},{-1,1}}
```

and rest of the blocks are `{{0,0},{0,0}}`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the undocumented internal function: `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``:

```
A = 
 {{3, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0},
 {-1, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 {-1, 0, 0, 2, -1, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0},
 {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -1},
 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1}}

output = Internal`PartitionRagged[A, {{1, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2}}]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{{3}},{{-1,0}},{{-1,0}},{{-1,0}}},
>  {{{-1},{0}},{{2,-1},{-1,1}},{{0,0},{0,0}},{{0,0},{0,0}}},
>  {{{-1},{0}},{{0,0},{0,0}},{{2,-1},{-1,1}},{{0,0},{0,0}}},
>  {{{-1},{0}},{{0,0},{0,0}},{{0,0},{0,0}},{{2,-1},{-1,1}}}
> }
> ```

A corresponding [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html):

```
Grid[A, Dividers -> {{True, {True, False}}, {True, {True, False}}}]
```

[image]

You can recombine the partitions with [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) if needed:

```
ArrayFlatten[output] == A
```

> ```
> True
> ```